# How to set dynamic url for angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

My address bar url is

```
hostname/admin/Usergroup_controller/view_members/1
```

I am calling internally using angular js

```
hostname/admin/Usergroup_controller/get_view_members/1
```

Here last is id which is now 1 but can be change.

I want to pass that url in following code

```
$http.get(site_url + 'hostname/admin/Usergroup_controller/get_view_members/1').success(function (data) {}
```

How can I ???

Hope you understand

Comment: `var id = 1; $http.get(site_url + 'hostname/admin/Usergroup_controller/get_view_members/' + id).....`

Comment: Can someone use Angular and be blocked by a problem like that ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux by a problem like what?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understand that you want to include the 'id' in the browser url, like `hostname/admin/Usergroup_controller/view_members/1` and thereby want to perform a GET request using that 'id' as in `$http.get(site_url + 'hostname/admin/Usergroup_controller/get_view_members/1')`

I am assuming that you are using `$routeProvider` (Angular Routing). Now that means that you need to tweak the `.when(path, route)` method to pass the dynamic 'id' in the browser's url. So, the `.when(path, route)` will be like `.when('/Usergroup_controller/view_members/:id', templateUrl: 'viewMembers.html')`; assuming `viewMembers.html` is the page you want to route to.

After, changing the `.when(path, route)` you will need to extract the value of `:id` from the browser's url. That will be done by using `$routeParams` in the controller of the routed page which in this case will be `viewMembers.html`. In the controller of `viewMembers.html` you need to extract the value of `:id` by writting this:

```
$scope.idEnteredInBrowserUrl=$routeParams.id;
```

Now, you will need to pass the value, `$scope.idEnteredInBrowserUrl` in the service from which you will be performing the `$http.get()` request. This can be done by creating a function in the service, say

```
var setIdEnteredInBrowserUrl = function (id) {
  $http.get(site_url +  'hostname/admin/Usergroup_controller/get_view_members/'+id).success(function    (data) {}}
```

Please note that the `$http.get()` is mentioned inside the setter function because you want the `$http.get()` to be called only after this method has been called and you have to `:id` value to append it to the GET request URL.

Call this method from the controller of the `viewMembers.html` and pass the extracted `:id` value, `$scope.idEnteredInBrowserUrl` to the service.