# Integrating paypal sandbox in php

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal sandbox in php.

I have code below

```
<?php
$paypalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; 
$paypalID = 'dnyaneshk8.business@gmail.com'; //Business Email

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>PayPal Standard Payment Gateway Integration by CodexWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>Name: Movie Kabaali
<br/>Price: 101
<form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID;             ?>">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Kabali movie ticket">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="101">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="2">

    <!-- Specify URLs -->
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/paypal_jatin/cancel.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/paypal_jatin/success.php'>

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This code working but when payment is successful, it not returning to my site immediately.

It is giving message like

```
 you've just completed your payment.
```

And then after that below two links are there

1 . Return to Dyanesh Business's Test Store

2 . Go to PayPal account overview

I want that when transaction successful user should redirected to the localhost.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You should study routing in angular. https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router may be a good place to start

Comment: You have to improve your question. Where are you calling this $http.get? inside controller or service, factory. Based on this location the idea of id can be determined in many ways. If possible give a jsfiddle example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131745/how-to-set-dynamic-url-for-angular-js Isnt this the same question you asked before. Try doing what @binariedMe said

Comment: @SridharGudimela added the controller code

Answer (score 0):

You are returning to Dyanesh Business's Test Store because you are using his key use your own key by making an account on sandbox.